# adding pointers to a stack C

Tags: c, pointers, stack

I have a stack that will hold a BIGINT. A bigint is a struct that has a char array that will hold our numbers, and some other values. So I made my stack, and everything worked well from the STDIN, but when I try to add a a bigint, it seems like nothing is being added. here is my `push_stack()` code:

```
void push_stack (stack *this, stack_item item) {
    if (full_stack (this)){realloc_stack (this);}
    this->data[this->size] = strdup(item);
    this->size++;
}
```

Here is my `stack` structure:

```
 struct stack {
   size_t capacity;
   size_t size;
   stack_item *data;
};
```

Here is my `bigint` structure:

```
struct bigint {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    bool negative;
    char *digits;
};

bigint *new_string_bigint (char *string) {
    assert (string != NULL);
    size_t length = strlen (string);
    bigint *this = new_bigint (length > MIN_CAPACITY ? length : MIN_CAPACITY);
    char *strdigit = &string[length - 1];
    if (*string == '_') {
       this->negative = true;
       ++string;
    }
    char *thisdigit = this->digits;
    while (strdigit >= string) {
        assert (isdigit (*strdigit));
        *thisdigit++ = *strdigit-- - '0';
    }
    this->size = thisdigit - this->digits;
    trim_zeros (this);
    return this;
}
```

And now my additon to the stack:

```
void do_push (stack *stack, char *numstr) {
    bigint *bigint = new_string_bigint (numstr);
    show_bigint(bigint);
    push_stack(stack, bigint);
}
```

For some reason, my `bigint` will not add to the stack. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it because I am using strdup?

Comment: You have not included stack definition

Comment: what is `stack_item`? Unless it's a `char*` to a 0 terminated string you can't `strdup()` it.

Comment: What does your realloc_stack function look like?

Comment: Why don't you just assign the pointer directly? Are you trying to use `strdup` to create a copy of the `bigint` (which won't work, since a `bigint` isn't a string)?  Otherwise, why not just do `this->data[this->size] = item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `push_stack()` passing a pointer to a `bigint`.

`push_stack()` is expecting a `stack_item` (not a pointer to a bigint).

You then `strdup()` the item (which is not a `char*` to a 0 terminated string as expected by strdup).

You should have received compiler warnings when you built this. Try fixing those first!

Comment: stack_item is a a generic data type thou

Comment: A generic data type in C? How have you defined it? `void*`?

Comment: What he's saying is: You can't use `strdup` on anything other than a `char *` (or something that points to a null-terminated string atleast), but since you're trying to do that you should have received compiler warnings (and non-working code ofcourse).

Comment: what should I use instead of strdup?

Comment: should i have the stack point to bigints->digits ? that is a char*

Comment: You still haven't told us what `stack_item` is. Is it a typedef? a #define, a different structure? @ccKep is correct though. One of the biggest issue is that you are passing the wrong data type to `strdup()` and it wont be behaving as you expect. If you fix your compiler warnings, this might become clearer.

Comment: You might want to think about picking up a book regarding C programming. What you should / shouldn't do depends on how you want to manage your memory (eg. who's responsible for free'ing the allocated memory if you chose to take that road). Most C programming books have dedicated sections on programming stacks, linked lists etc. and how to manage memory with them.